# jquery ajax load php into specified div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to load a php file into a div`#main` when a link is clicked. The html content loads but the actual php code included in the file does not. Here's what I've got:

**Link to trigger everything:**

```
<a id="nav" href="http://domain.com/inc/file.php">
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#nav").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#main").empty();

        $.ajax({
            url: $("#nav").attr('href')
        }).done(function(data) { 
            $('#main').html(data); // display data
        });
    }); 

});
```

**Code from `file.php` (mostly WordPress functions):**

```
<div id="hostels" class="section cf">

    <?php get_a_post(31); ?>

    <article id="swiss" <?php post_class('swiss bg col span-1-3'); ?> role="article">
        <h3>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <span class="logo-pl-small"><?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/library/svg/logo.svg'); ?></span>
                <span class="">Swiss Cottage &ndash; London UK</span>
            </a>
        </h3>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'bonestheme' ) ); ?>
            <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vidlink', true) ) { 
                echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vidlink', true)); 
            } ?>
         </div>
    </article>

</div>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="hostels" class="section cf">
    </div>
</div>
```

The file begins to load but as soon as `<?php get_a_post(31); ?>` is reached, the file does not continue to load.

I could be wrong, but I thought that by using `$.ajax` the php code would execute on the server and code it outputs would load into my `#main` div.

Comment: Check for script error. I don't know wordpress but maybe you cannot call this method like this

Comment: Try to add `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` in the beginning of `file.php`

Comment: The code works fine when replicated. So the error is in your PHP.  Run `http://domain.com/inc/file.php` in your browser and see what happends / the output is.

Comment: @Zub Thanks for the tip. I'm getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_a_post()`. I'm going to try some generic php to see if that works, then may need to use a different method.

Comment: seems you need to activate / install / withdraw a plugin -> http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-get_a_post-in, you propably not have all included in your (guessing) selfmade file.php?

Comment: @davidkonrad I had the same thoughts but when running generic Wordpress loop php code I get similar errors.

Comment: The strange thing is when I call the external file via `<?php get_template_part('inc/file'); ?>` it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've got this *somewhat* working. 
I found [this tutorial for Ajax Powered Loops with jQuery and WordPress](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress/) from which I discovered that (as I had guessed) the files I created need to understand WordPress functions. For this I need to include:

```
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
```

In my case that's the relevant path from `file.php`.

There's still some issues such as shortcodes generated from plugins not working fully, but that's beyond the scope of my original question.

There's a lot of useful info relating to ajax and Wordpress in the tutorial above though, if anyone is having similar issues I'd recommend having a read.

Comment: +1, you could accept your own answer, maybe helping other people in the future. Regarding `../../../../wp-load.php`, there _must_ be an easy-accessible path-variable in wordpress. But cannot say/remember, gave it up years ago, dont think WP expose good programming practise or a transparent model, imho.

Comment: @davidkonrad You might be able to use `home_url( 'wp-load.php' );`. Can't accept my own answer for a couple of days. Will come back to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$.ajax({
  url: $("#nav").attr('href')
}).done(function(data) { 
  $('#main').html(data); // display data
});
```

why not the more simple

```
$("#main").load('http://domain.com/inc/file.php');
```

??

Comment: doesn't explain why OP code doesn't work but ya load() would be more accurate here

Comment: In this case, `.load()` wasn't loading the content into `#main` but linking to the full page.